# How to unlock Glassfish server.log.lck?

Tags: glassfish

I have a small problem in my Glassfish logs directory. Logs directory is located in glassfish/domains/domain1/. The problem is that the Glassfish won't update server.log file whenever I do some change to my web application which uses Glassfish as a server. This used to work.

In logs directory there's also a file called server.log.lck, which means that it locks the server.log file and thus it won't update it. My question is that how I can unlock server.log file so that server.log file is being updated whenever I get an error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be sufficient to delete the file `server.log.lck` to get Glassfish writing to the `server.log` again. If you can't delete the file because it "is in use", you have to stop Glassfish and delete the file.

PS: If you are on Windows and the problem occurs again, it may be a problem with the access rights for the Glassfish domain folder.

Comment: That was the solution for the problem. I had to stop the Glassfish because it seem to be running. So then you need to delete .lck file if it is not deleted automatically :). Thanks.

Comment: For me it was wrong access rights for server.log file, it was owned by root, glassfish user could not write to file...

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, this issue was hit on Payara server v5.184 (based on Glassfish) running on an AWS EC2 instance. After the instance was rebooted, Payara would not start up.

The problem was the root file-system went into a read-only (ro) mode:

```
$ mount -l
/dev/xvda1 on / type xfs (ro,relatime,attr2,inode64,noquota) [/]
```

Was fixed by running

```
mount / -o remount,rw
```